# Primefaces inputtext triggers commandbutton issue

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an easy question.

I have few primefaces `inputtext` and two primefaces `commandbutton` on my xhtml page. When I press enter after edited the inputtext, it triggers one of my commandbutton.

But I want to trigger the other commandbutton. How to do that? And how it decide which `commandbutton` is to be triggered? What is the reason there?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`p:defaultCommand`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultCommand.xhtml)

```xhtml
<p:defaultCommand target="btnId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the "press enter event" in JavaScript and simulate a click on the button of your choice.

Something like this :

```
$('#yourInput').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#yourButton").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have more than one primafaces inputtext. In this solution I need to catch the enter event for each of them with js. Is it the correct solution for these kind of problems? I also look for the reason why it trigger that button but not the other. Thanks for help.

Comment: @rLyLmZ With jQuery you can use a single selector to catch multiple input `$("input[class='yourClass']")` or whatever. I'm guessing the reason why a button is triggered and not the other is their respective position in your code.